# Grid View Javascript Error in IE 11 and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, google-chrome

I have a GridView that has checkboxes and an "onClick" function "VerifyChecked" that is attached to each of the checboxes in the row data bound event of the Grid.

In my Javascript the function body is as shown below

```
 function VerifyChecked() {          
        var gv = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdProductNotes');
        var btn = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnAdd');
        var btn2 = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnAdd1');
        btn.disabled = true;
        btn2.disabled = true;
        var strEnabled;
        var strPk = '';
        var strSeq = '';
        var count = 0;
        for (i = 1; i < gv.rows.length; i++) {
            var row = gv.rows[i];
            var ckbox = row.cells[0].getElementsByTagName('input')
            if (ckbox[0].checked) {
                btn.disabled = false;
                btn2.disabled = false;
                count = count + 1;

                var pk = row.cells[0].all[2].innerText;
```

The application throws no error in Internet Explorer Version 10. 
However in version 11 and in chrome , when I check the Console. I am getting the below error .

**"UnCaught TypeError :Cannot read property 2 of undefined"**

The line causing the error is
`var pk = row.cells[0].all[2].innerText;`

EDIT 1:

I found out that the "Object.all" property is now obsolete due to which I am getting the errors. However now I an unable to access the elements of the all collection.Any workarounds to achieve this ?

[All property is obsolete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537434(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `children` or `childNodes` collections:

```
var pk = row.cells[0].children[2].innerText;
var pk = row.cells[0].childNodes[n].innerText;
```

Please note that `childNodes` also includes text nodes. The index of the element may therefore not be the same as for the obsolete `all` property.